# Resource union throws access violation for Fonts in SFML

Tags: c++, sfml, access-violation

So I am trying to write a Resource loader and manager (Yes I know of Thor, this is just a "learning" project.) and I have started experimenting with unions, not something I use very often. I created a class (as seen in code below) called resource which has a union that contains a texture/font. The texture loads correctly; however the font throws an access violation

```
Exception thrown at 0x00C5DBE0 in Project.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000004.
```

The following is my complete and minimal example. EDIT:: Updated code solves the problem. Evan explained below that this is because only the first element in a union is default constructed.

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Resource
{
public:
    union
    {
        sf::Texture t;
        sf::Font    f;
    };

    Resource(sf::Font font = sf::Font()) : f(font)
    {                                            }

    ~Resource()
    {         }
};

int main()
{
    Resource font;
    Resource tex;

    if (!tex.t.loadFromFile("player.png")) {}   //! Works great!
        //doError

    if (!font.f.loadFromFile("blocks.ttf")) {}  //! Throws access violation.
        //doError

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Without the definitions of sf::Texture and sf::Font it is impossible to tell what is happening, but I would guess that f hasn't been constructed properly.

Comment: Those are apart of the SFML library. It can indeed be constructed with the default constructor, as I did above.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if the problem is the SFML classes or your use of them? I tried implementing your problem with a `string` and `vector` and had problems myself. If you can recreate the problem with stl you can reach a wider audience

Comment: The memory regions for members of a union overlap. Only the first one gets default constructed, if there is any memory left over, it's full of garbage.

Comment: It appears that I do have to explicitly construct `f` by doing so: `Resource(sf::Font font = sf::Font()) : f(font)`. Does anyone know why this might be? (I am updating main post)

EDIT: Just as I posted this Evan explained it. Thank you!

Comment: @evan Do you mind making an answer so I can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that `f` is unitialized. The memory regions of the members of a union overlap, and unless you tell the compiler otherwise, only the first member gets initialized.

You can initialize them yourself either in a constructor, or by using placement new.

```
new (&f) sf::Font;
```

Also, destructing the union will cause problems, because the compiler doesn't know which member to destruct, and it will need to be done manually like

```
f.~sf::Font();
```

Comment: Where would I put `new (&f) sf::Font;`? In a constructor, or in the union itself? Or in the main function?

Comment: In `main` before `font.f.loadF...` add `new (&font.f) sf::Font;`